# Specified cast is not valid error using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to store a select statement result in C# variable but getting this error

> "Specified cast is not valid"

when i run it.  I am not sure how to resolve it please help

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select cast(round(sum(CAST(AvgNumbers AS numeric(12,2))),2) as decimal(12,2)) AS [Average Days] from MainTable ", con1);

        cmd1.Connection = con1;
        con1.Open();
        Int32 result = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
        con1.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmd1.ExecuteScalar()` is not returning a boxed integer. Assign it to an object and look at it in the debugger to see what it really is.

I'm guessing it's going to be returning a Decimal or a double, and you need to do:

```
Int32 result = (Int32)(double)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Or:

```
Int32 result = (Int32)(Decimal)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

[EDIT in response to a question in commments below]

To keep the decimal value, just do this:

```
Decimal result = (Decimal) cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

If you needed to, you could cast the decimal to a double:

```
double result = (double)(Decimal) cmd1.ExectuteScalar();
```

Comment: thanks Mathew, your second approach worked like a charm but i was expecting this number 27.81 and i am getting just only 27.  Is there a way i can show the decimals too?  thanks

Comment: +1. The problem is not that you can't cast a decimal to an int, but that you can't cast a boxed decimal to an int.

Comment: An integer by definition won't have any decimal places. The solution in your case is to use a decimal instead. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

The result isn't an `Int32`, basically. You're casting it to `Decimal(12, 2)` - so I'm not sure why you'd expect it to.

My guess is that it'll either be a `double` or a `decimal` - but if you separate the call from the cast and look in the debugger, it should be obvious:

```
object result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
// Now look at the type of the value of result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result isn' an `Int32` obviosly, so you can use it;

```
var result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

After that, you can check it out which type it is. Or use;

```
object result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Than maybe you can cast it. Just remember, you can look it in debugger easyly.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the value as a decimal in the SQL, so try casting as a decimal in your c# code.