# Specified cast is not valid error in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, casting

How do I resolve this?

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnectionstring);
string validateinventory = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inventory_register WHERE barcode = @barcode";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(validateinventory,con);

con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", textBox3.Text);
int Result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();

if (Result > 0)
{
    textBox3.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Barcode! Please Register Inventory or Enter Valid Barcode");
}
```

An InvalidCastException is thrown in the following line:

```
int Result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Perhaps you should state the error you're getting, and on which line.

Comment: Hi.i am getting the error in the line "int result = (int)cmd.executescalar();

Comment: @Ameena Are you sure the result of `ExecuteScalar()` is an integer value? What does the debugger say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specified cast is not valid error using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944254/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-using-c-sharp)

Comment: What is the actual return value from ExecuteScalar?

Comment: @Andy i want to check if the barcode(which is double in DB) already exists in the table or not. i had tried similar code for string value (eg:username) with if condition as "if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strResult))" and it worked.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal `null` is being returned only if the result set is empty, which can't be while using the `COUNT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to debug such code:

```
object Result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I think that this will be a `decimal`, but it's depends on the MySQL behaviour. And in C# you can't simply convert a `double` to the `int`, **if it is boxed**. Just get the correct type and convert to it, and only after that you can convert to `int`, like this:

```
int Result = (int)(decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also, you can get the `object` via `var` keyword, and use the `Convert` class:

```
var objectResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int Result = Convert.ToInt32(objectResult);
```

Comment: In C#, you absolutely can explicitly cast a double to an integer. Why should `COUNT` return a double?

Comment: @Frank `decimal` or double will throw an exception in checked context, as the `double` value is boxed, and need to be converted to it's real type before. This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14944290/213550

Comment: @VMAtm thank you. now the problem comes to if condition,how should i check if the value of Result is not null or null (>0 or =0)